# Converting ASCII to Decimal C microcontroller bluetooth

Tags: c, bluetooth, decimal, ascii, microcontroller

I'm simply trying to convert ASCII to Decimal on my microcontroller (in C) before it is sent over bluetooth.

Control + F and find ASCII in this library. 
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB_C18_Libraries_51297f.pdf

This is the relevant section of my code.

```
PIR1bits.ADIF=0;
while(x ==1)
{
ConvertADC(); //ADCONbits.GO/DONE=1 , Starts the A/D conversion process.
while(BusyADC()){}                  // Wait for completion

Delay10KTCYx(0);
Delay10KTCYx(0);
Delay10KTCYx(0);
Delay10KTCYx(0);
while(BusyUSART());
putcUSART(ADRESH); //prints or places the character into bluetooth
while(BusyUSART());
putcUSART(ADRESL); //prints or places the character into bluetooth
PIR1bits.ADIF=0;
}
//CloseADC();       // Disable A/D converter

}
```

What I have tried.

1) atob(ADRESH) atob(ADRESL)

2) atof(ADRESH) atof(ADRESL)

3) atoi(ADRESH) atoi(ADRESL)

4) atol(ADRESH) atol(ADRESL)

5) putCUSART (atob/f/i/l(ADRESH)) putCUSART(atob/f/i/l(ADRESL)

This is my Full code

```
/*********************************************************************
 *
 *      Example User Program to be used with resident Bootloader
 *
 *********************************************************************
 * FileName:        main.c
 * File Version:    2.0, 15-February
 * Dependencies:    See INCLUDES section below
 * Processor:       PIC18
 * Compiler:        C18 2.30.01+
 * Company:         emxys Ltd.
 *
 *
 *
 * Copyright: 2009 emxys Ltd.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
 *
 * Notes: This is a basic template for PIC18F4550 running
 *        uIceBlue module.
 *
 ********************************************************************/

#define PROGRAMMABLE_WITH_USB_HID_BOOTLOADER


/** INCLUDES *******************************************************/

#include <p18cxxx.h>
#include <portb.h>
#include <usart.h>
#include <delays.h>
#include <adc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/** CONFIGURATION **************************************************/


/** V A R I A B L E S **********************************************/
#pragma idata
int i=0;        //number of characters of command
int x=1;
int y=1;
/** PRIVATE PROTOTYPES *********************************************/

void YourHighPriorityISRCode();
void YourLowPriorityISRCode();


/** VECTOR REMAPPING ***********************************************/
    #if defined(PROGRAMMABLE_WITH_USB_HID_BOOTLOADER)
        #define REMAPPED_RESET_VECTOR_ADDRESS           0x1000
        #define REMAPPED_HIGH_INTERRUPT_VECTOR_ADDRESS  0x1008
        #define REMAPPED_LOW_INTERRUPT_VECTOR_ADDRESS   0x1018
    #endif

    #if defined(PROGRAMMABLE_WITH_USB_HID_BOOTLOADER)
        extern void _startup (void);        // See c018i.c in your C18 compiler dir
        #pragma code REMAPPED_RESET_VECTOR = REMAPPED_RESET_VECTOR_ADDRESS
        void _reset (void)
        {
            _asm goto _startup _endasm
        }
    #endif

    #pragma code REMAPPED_HIGH_INTERRUPT_VECTOR = REMAPPED_HIGH_INTERRUPT_VECTOR_ADDRESS
        void Remapped_High_ISR (void)
        {
             _asm goto YourHighPriorityISRCode _endasm
        }

    #pragma code REMAPPED_LOW_INTERRUPT_VECTOR = REMAPPED_LOW_INTERRUPT_VECTOR_ADDRESS
        void Remapped_Low_ISR (void)
        {
             _asm goto YourLowPriorityISRCode _endasm
        }

    #if defined(PROGRAMMABLE_WITH_USB_HID_BOOTLOADER)
    //Note: If this project is built while one of the bootloaders has
    //been defined, but then the output hex file is not programmed with
    //the bootloader, addresses 0x08 and 0x18 would end up programmed with 0xFFFF.
    //As a result, if an actual interrupt was enabled and occured, the PC would jump
    //to 0x08 (or 0x18) and would begin executing "0xFFFF" (unprogrammed space).  This
    //executes as nop instructions, but the PC would eventually reach the REMAPPED_RESET_VECTOR_ADDRESS
    //(0x1000 or 0x800, depending upon bootloader), and would execute the "goto _startup".  This
    //would effective reset the application.

    //To fix this situation, we should always deliberately place a
    //"goto REMAPPED_HIGH_INTERRUPT_VECTOR_ADDRESS" at address 0x08, and a
    //"goto REMAPPED_LOW_INTERRUPT_VECTOR_ADDRESS" at address 0x18.  When the output
    //hex file of this project is programmed with the bootloader, these sections do not
    //get bootloaded (as they overlap the bootloader space).  If the output hex file is not
    //programmed using the bootloader, then the below goto instructions do get programmed,
    //and the hex file still works like normal.  The below section is only required to fix this
    //scenario.
        #pragma code HIGH_INTERRUPT_VECTOR = 0x08
        void High_ISR (void)
        {
             _asm goto REMAPPED_HIGH_INTERRUPT_VECTOR_ADDRESS _endasm
        }
        #pragma code LOW_INTERRUPT_VECTOR = 0x18
        void Low_ISR (void)
        {
             _asm goto REMAPPED_LOW_INTERRUPT_VECTOR_ADDRESS _endasm
        }
    #endif  //end of "#if defined(PROGRAMMABLE_WITH_USB_HID_BOOTLOADER)||defined(PROGRAMMABLE_WITH_USB_LEGACY_CUSTOM_CLASS_BOOTLOADER)"

    #pragma code


    //These are your actual interrupt handling routines.
    #pragma interrupt YourHighPriorityISRCode
    void YourHighPriorityISRCode()
    {
        unsigned char buffer[40];

        if (PIR1bits.RCIF == 1)    //USART Interruption
        {
            buffer[i]= getcUSART();     //characters of the commands.

            if (buffer[i]=='\n')
                buffer[i]='\r';

            if (i<4 & buffer[i]=='\r')
            {
                RCREG=0;            // clear buffer
                TXREG=0;
                i=0;
                PIR1bits.RCIF =0;
                _asm RETFIE 0x0 _endasm

            }
            else  if (i==4 & buffer[4]=='\r')
            {

        /** PORTD commands *************************************************************/

        //COMMAND: 0xhi or 0xHI : set bit x from PORTD

                if ((buffer [0] == '0' & buffer[2] == 'h' & buffer[3]== 'i') || (buffer[0] == '0' & buffer[2] == 'H' & buffer[3]== 'I'))
                {
                    switch (buffer[1])
                    {
                        case '0':
                            PORTDbits.RD0 = 1;
                            break;
                        case '1':
                            PORTDbits.RD1 = 1;
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            PORTDbits.RD2 = 1;
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            PORTDbits.RD3 = 1;
                            break;
                        case '4':
                            PORTDbits.RD4 = 1;
                            break;
                        case '5':
                            PORTDbits.RD5 = 1;
                            break;
                        case '6':
                            PORTDbits.RD6 = 1;
                            break;
                        case '7':
                            PORTDbits.RD7 = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                    putcUSART('#');
                    WriteUSART(buffer[1]);
                    putrsUSART("HI");
                }

        //COMMAND: 0xlo or 0xLO : clear bit x from PORTD

                if ((buffer[0] == '0' & buffer[2] == 'l' & buffer[3]== 'o') || (buffer [0] == '0' & buffer[2] == 'L' & buffer[3]== 'O'))
                {

                    switch (buffer[1])
                    {
                        case '0':
                            PORTDbits.RD0 = 0;
                            break;
                        case '1':
                            PORTDbits.RD1 = 0;
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            PORTDbits.RD2 = 0;
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            PORTDbits.RD3 = 0;
                            break;
                        case '4':
                            PORTDbits.RD4 = 0;
                            break;
                        case '5':
                            PORTDbits.RD5 = 0;
                            break;
                        case '6':
                            PORTDbits.RD6 = 0;
                            break;
                        case '7':
                            PORTDbits.RD7 = 0;
                            break;
                    }
                    putcUSART('#');
                    WriteUSART(buffer[1]);
                    putrsUSART("LO");
                }

        //COMMAND: aclr or ACLR : clear PORTD

                if ((buffer[0] == 'a' & buffer[1] == 'c' & buffer[2]== 'l' & buffer[3] == 'r') || ( buffer[0] == 'A' & buffer[1] == 'C' & buffer[2]== 'L' & buffer[3] == 'R'))
                {
                    PORTD= 0x00;
                }

        //COMMAND: aset or ASET : set PORTD

                if ((buffer[0] == 'a' & buffer[1] == 's' & buffer[2]== 'e' & buffer[3] == 't') || ( buffer[0] == 'A' & buffer[1] == 'S' & buffer[2]== 'E' & buffer[3] == 'T'))
                {
                    PORTD= 0xFF;
                }

        //COMMAND: dqst or DQST : query state of PORTD

                if ((buffer[0] == 'd' & buffer[1] == 'q' & buffer[2]== 's' & buffer[3] == 't') || ( buffer[0] == 'D' & buffer[1] == 'Q' & buffer[2]== 'S' & buffer[3] == 'T'))
                {
                    putcUSART('#');
                    WriteUSART(PORTD);
                }

        //COMMAND: dldx or DLDx : load the value x on PORTD

                if ((buffer[0] == 'd' & buffer[1]== 'l' & buffer[2] == 'd') || ( buffer[0] == 'D' & buffer[1]== 'L' & buffer[2] == 'D'))
                {
                    PORTD= buffer[3];
                }


        /** PORTB commands *************************************************************/

        //COMMAND: bqst or BQST : query state of PORTB

                if ((buffer[0] == 'b' & buffer[1] == 'q' & buffer[2]== 's' & buffer[3] == 't') || ( buffer[0] == 'B' & buffer[1] == 'Q' & buffer[2]== 'S' & buffer[3] == 'T'))
                {
                    putcUSART('#');
                    WriteUSART(PORTB);
                }


        //COMMAND: 0xst or 0xST : show the state of bit x from PORTB

                if ((buffer[0] == '0' & buffer[2]== 's' & buffer[3] == 't') || ( buffer[0] == '0' & buffer[2]== 'S' & buffer[3] == 'T'))
                {
                    unsigned status;
                    switch (buffer[1])
                    {
                        case '0':
                            status = PORTBbits.RB0;
                            break;
                        case '1':
                            status = PORTBbits.RB1;
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            status = PORTBbits.RB2;
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            status = PORTBbits.RB3;
                            break;
                        case '4':
                            status = PORTBbits.RB4;
                            break;
                        case '5':
                            status = PORTBbits.RB5;
                            break;
                        case '6':
                            status = PORTBbits.RB6;
                            break;
                        case '7':
                            status = PORTBbits.RB7;
                            break;
                    }
                    putcUSART('#');
                    WriteUSART(buffer[1]);
                    if (status)
                        putrsUSART("HI");
                    else
                        putrsUSART("LO");


                }


        /** AD converter commands *************************************************************/

        //COMMAND: 0xad or 0xAD : x will be the input for the AD converter

                if ((buffer[0] == '0' & buffer[2]== 'a' & buffer[3] == 'd') || ( buffer[0] == '0' & buffer[2]== 'A' & buffer[3] == 'D'))
                {

                    switch (buffer[1])
                    {
                        case '0':
                            SetChanADC( ADC_CH0 );
                            break;
                        case '1':
                            SetChanADC( ADC_CH1 );
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            SetChanADC( ADC_CH2 );
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            SetChanADC( ADC_CH3 );
                            break;
                        case '4':
                            SetChanADC( ADC_CH4 );
                            break;
                        case '5':
                            SetChanADC( ADC_CH5 );
                            break;
                        case '6':
                            SetChanADC( ADC_CH6 );
                            break;
                        case '7':
                            SetChanADC( ADC_CH7 );
                            break;
                    }

                PIR1bits.ADIF=0;

                                while(x ==1)
                                {

                ConvertADC();
                                                //ADCONbits.GO/DONE=1 , Starts the A/D conversion process.

                while(BusyADC())
                {}                  // Wait for completion

                //putcUSART('\n');
                                Delay10KTCYx(0);
                                Delay10KTCYx(0);
                                Delay10KTCYx(0);
                                Delay10KTCYx(0);
                while(BusyUSART());
                putcUSART(ADRESH);
                while(BusyUSART());
                putcUSART(ADRESL);

                PIR1bits.ADIF=0;
                                }
                //CloseADC();       // Disable A/D converter

                }
            i=-1;
            PIR1bits.RCIF =0;
            }
            else if (i>4 & buffer[i]=='\r')
            {
                RCREG=0;            //Clear the buffer
                TXREG=0;
                i=0;
                PIR1bits.RCIF =0;
                _asm RETFIE 0x0 _endasm
            }

            i++;

}


    }   //This return will be a "retfie fast", since this is in a #pragma interrupt section
    #pragma interruptlow YourLowPriorityISRCode
    void YourLowPriorityISRCode()
    {
        //Check which interrupt flag caused the interrupt.
        //Service the interrupt
        //Clear the interrupt flag
        //Etc.





    }   //This return will be a "retfie", since this is in a #pragma interruptlow section


/** DECLARATIONS ***************************************************/
#pragma code


/******************************************************************************
 * Function:        void main(void)
 *
 * PreCondition:    None
 *
 * Input:           None
 *
 * Output:          None
 *
 * Side Effects:    None
 *
 * Overview:        Main program entry point.
 *
 * Note:            None
 *****************************************************************************/

void main(void)
{
    //Configure Ports : 1 is input, 0 is output

    TRISA=1;
    TRISB=1;
    PORTB=0;
    TRISD=0;
    PORTD=0;
    TRISE=1;

//Configure Interruptions

    INTCONbits.GIE=1;   // Global Interruption Enable bit
    INTCONbits.PEIE=1;  // Peripheral Interruption Enable bit
    //PIE1bits.TXIE=1;  // EUSART Transmit Interruption Enable bit
    PIE1bits.RCIE=1;    // EUSART Receive Interruption Enable bit
    IPR1bits.RCIP=1;    // EUSART Receive Interruption Priority bit

//Configure USART

    //configure RC6/TX/CK and RC7/RX/DT/SDO as an EUSART
    TRISCbits.TRISC6=1;
    TRISCbits.TRISC7=1;
    RCSTAbits.SPEN=1;   //Serial Port Enable bit
    BAUDCONbits.BRG16=0;//16-Bit Baud Rate Register Enable bit


    /* EUSART BAUD RATE CONFIGURATION ***********************************
    ;OpenUSART(...,SPBRG) configure the USART
    ;
    ; SPBRG value =>    312 @ 9600    bauds
    ;                   155 @ 19200   bauds
    ;                   77  @ 38400   bauds
    ;                   51  @ 57600   bauds
    ;                   25  @ 115200  bauds
    ;                   12  @ 230400  bauds
    ;                   6   @ 460800  bauds
    ;                   2   @ 921600  bauds
    ;
    ; Check the MPLAB C18 Libraries and the 18F4550 datasheet for more
    ; information
    ********************************************************************/

    OpenUSART(USART_TX_INT_OFF &        //Interruption on Transmission
                USART_RX_INT_ON &       //Interruption on Receipt
                USART_ASYNCH_MODE &     //USART Mode
                USART_EIGHT_BIT &       //Transmission Width
                USART_CONT_RX &         //Reception mode
                USART_BRGH_HIGH, 155);  //High Baud Rate Select bit, Baud rate at which the USART operates


//Configure AD converter

    ADCON0bits.ADON=1;      //Enable AD converter

    /* AD converter configuration *******************************************
    ;OpenADC(...,portconfig) configure the AD converter
    ;
    ;   portconfig value => A/D Port Configuration Control bits in decimal
    ;
    ; The channel for the A/D conversion is selected by a command
    ;
    ; Default Vref+ = Vdd, default Vref- = Vss
    ;
    ; Check the MPLAB C18 Libraries and the 18F4550 datasheet for more
    ; information
    ************************************************************************/

    OpenADC( ADC_FOSC_64 &              //clock source
            ADC_RIGHT_JUST &            //result justification
            ADC_20_TAD,                 //acquisition time selected must be TAD>0,7us.
            ADC_INT_OFF &               //interruptions off
            ADC_VREFPLUS_VDD &          //Voltage reference
            ADC_VREFMINUS_VSS, 7 );     //Port configuration is any value from 0 to 15 inclusive


    while(1)
        {

        //INSERT YOUR MAIN CODE HERE

        }



}//end main





/** EOF main.c *************************************************************/
```

Comment: What sort of output do you get? From the `atob` definition, I'm assuming that ADRESH and ADRESL are null-terminated strings. Where do these get set? In general, the result of reading an analog to digital conversion will already give you a binary value. Are you sure you're getting strings? And where are you performing the `ReadADC()` call to retrieve the result of the last conversion?

Comment: hey this isn't the full code. Strangely enough, I couldn't not find ADRESH OR ADRESL defined anywhere in the code. I'm assuming those were hard-coded into the microcontroller. I am getting ASCII values, I've tested it on hyperterminal. I don't think I'm getting strings, I think I'm only getting characters printed. I'll put up the full code.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this right, when sending the command you're getting two characters like '7', '1' and instead you want a binary value 71 (0x47, ASCII character "G")? It seems like ADRESH and ADRESL are two characters representing the high and low order digits of the conversion result. Both registers will have a value of 0x30-0x39, so this should work: `char val = (ADRESH & 0x0F) << 4 | (ADRESL & 0x0F)`. This only works if your A/D conversion values are actually 0 - 99.

Comment: When I send a command, I get a single ASCII character- G or R or Z etc - per a conversion. I would like the decimal system value, like 71 or 73. How would I increase the range from 0-999 or 0-9999?

Comment: Ok, I think we're finally getting down to the root here. Your question was asked backwards from the way people normally state the problem. You have binary values and want an ASCII text string instead. Is the A/D 16 bits? And the analog input is near zero? I expect you're getting two character, only one of which is printable and the other is a null or non-printing control character. Treat the ADRESH and ADRESL as the two bytes of a 16-bit integer, use sprintf to format a string and send that string to the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

`ADRESH` and `ADRESL` are both 8-bit byte variables. They need to be converted to an ASCII string.

`atob()` / `atof()` / `atoi()` / `atol()` convert an ASCII string to a byte/float/integer/long value. You pass them a string and they return a number.

```
char    atob(const char * s); // convert string to 8-bit signed character
double  atof(const char * s); // convert string to floating point value
int     atoi(const char * s); // convert string to 16-bit signed integer
long    atol(const char * s); // convert string to long integer representation
```

You want to use the `btoa()` / `itoa()` / `ltoa()` (byte/integer/long to ASCII) functions. You pass them the value to convert along with a character buffer for storing the string. They return the string representation of the passed value.

```
char *  btoa(char value, char * string); // convert byte value to string
char *  itoa( int value, char * string); // convert integer value to string
char *  ltoa(long value, char * string); // convert long value to string
```

In your case, you'll want to use `btoa()` (or `itoa()` if you combine `ADRESH` and `ADRESL`) and `putsUSART()`.

```
char string[5];
while(BusyUSART());
putsUSART(btoa(ADRESH, string)); // prints high byte to bluetooth
while(BusyUSART());
putsUSART(btoa(ADRESL, string)); // prints low byte to bluetooth
```

or

```
char string[7];
unsigned int value = (unsigned int) ADRESH * 256 + ADRESL; // reassemble reading
while(BusyUSART());
putsUSART(itoa(value, string)); // prints ADC reading to bluetooth
```

Since you are using the string library (`#include <string.h>`), another option is to print a formatted output to a string using (`sprintf()`). The code would now be:

```
char string[9];
sprintf(string, "%d %d", ADRESH, ADRESL); // convert values to string
while(BusyUSART());
putsUSART(string); // prints ADC readings to bluetooth
```

or

```
char string[7];
unsigned int value = (unsigned int) ADRESH * 256 + ADRESL; // reassemble reading
sprintf(string, "%d", value); // convert value to string
while(BusyUSART());
putsUSART(string); // prints ADC reading to bluetooth
```